# Double state change in ui-router when using $state.go in $stateChangeStart

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

Here's my [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Zds0fulNOUHobjUOfMYv?p=preview). If you click on the `profile` link and look at the generated state change list:

```
stateChanges = [
  " -> home",
  "home -> profile",
  "home -> signIn",
  "signIn -> signIn"
]
```

you can see there's an unexpected extra state change `"signIn -> signIn"`.

I've done some debugging and it seems it's ui-router's reaction to `$locationChangeSuccess` via the `afterLocationChange` function. But I'm not sure if that's a bug in ui-router or a result of how I configured ui-router and how I manage redirection. If the behavior is my fault, how do I fix it?

I would really appreciate the help, as the double state change causes my query parameters to be double URL encoded: `/profile -> %2Fprofile -> %252Fprofile` instead of just the first two.

### UPDATE

It seems this is something that came with 0.2.15. I tried using older releases and even 0.2.14 works fine. After some investigation I found the problem came with commit [`48aeaff`](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/commit/48aeaff645baf3f42f5a8940ebd97563791ad9f8). If I uncomment the code that was commented out by that commit, this issue goes away even on 0.2.15. For now I will use this modified version of the 0.2.15.

I also found that there's an issue in ui-router's issue tracker for this [`#1573`](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/1573).

Answer (score 0):

kkIt looks like the problem lies in the Querystring you added in your `$stateProvider`

[plunkr Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/o3b11y5mh9RFMwlRUWnB?p=preview)

```
    .state("signIn", {
        parent: "frontpage",
        url: "/signIn?returnTo", // <--- remove the ?returnTo
        authorized: false,
        views: {
            "main@frontpage": {
                template: "sign in page"
            }
        }
    })
```

When this is changed to simply `/signIn` it should be fine. You might not be able to put `?queryStrings` in your `stateProvider` allocations.

```
        url: "/signIn" // It should work fine
```

Comment: On the ui-router github page there's [a section on query parameters](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing#query-parameters) which I followed. Query parameters are supposed to be option as well. So the ```returnTo``` doesn't need to be defined. I also tried with regular parameters (```"/signIn/:returnTo"```) which produces the same result. I played around with just ```/signIn``` but I haven't had any luck getting the ```returnTo``` parameter passed to ```signIn```. Not via ```$stateParams``` or via ```$location.search()```.

Answer (score 0):

As I went through your code, I found this block:

```
else if (authorized === true)
        {
            if (!service.authentication.authorized) {
                $state.go("signIn", {
                    returnTo: toState.url
                });
            }
        }
```

When you actually click from Home --> Profile, you would observer that authorized = true, and service.authentication.authorized = false. So, you're asking the browser to navigate to signIn state. However, you've clicked to Profile, and you're returning the browser to the same state that it was in.

I removed the statement `event.preventDefault();`from the above block, and it seems to be working fine now.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean. The ```authorized``` in the if condition refers to the ```authorized``` on the state object, not the state of user's authentication status. If it's set to ```true``` the state requires the user to be authenticated. If it's set to ```false```, the state is only for anonymous users. Else if it's ```undefined``` it's for everyone. If anon goes to profile, they will be redirected to signIn. If authenticated user goes to profile, the inner condition will fail and let them go through without doing anything. Or did I miss something?

Comment: @gligoran: I just removed the event.preventDefault() from the of block for (!service.authentication.authorized), and the double state issue is gone. Could you also check the same? Was there any specific reason for which you've added the same.

Comment: ```event.preventDefault()``` is there, so that state doesn't get resolved. In my actual application, the ```profile``` state makes and ```$http``` call to a back-end API, which will result in 401 if the user isn't authenticated. Then the interceptor will step in and mess everything up further.